# How to visually mark a "mandatory" form input widget?

Tags: gwt, gwt-material-design

What is the recommended way of (visually) marking a GwtMaterialDesign widget (in a form) as mandatory? (By mandatory I mean the usual "a user has to enter/select a value.")

Comment: https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout - section "Required field"

Comment: I was expecting something GMD-specific but good ol' asterisk is good enough :)